# AppendNode in a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, append, nodes

Whenever I go to use my showInfo function:
EDIT: it operates once but breaks the second time through.

```
void showInfo(){
    node * temp = head;
    while (temp){
        temp->showInfo();
        temp = temp->getNext();
    }
}
```

with temp->showInfo(); pointing at:

```
void showInfo(){
        cout << data << endl;
    }
```

I encounter the 0x0000005 error as it tries to access NULL. I'm assuming it's my appendNode function:

```
void appendNode(node * n){
        if (head == nullptr){
            head = n;
        }
        else{
            node * iter = head;
            while (iter->getNext()){
                iter = iter->getNext();
            }
            iter->setNext(n);
        }
        size++;
    }
```

The nodes are assigned as follows:

```
int main(){

    char * data1 = "g";
    char * data2 = "b";
    char * data3 = "k";

    linkedList * list = new linkedList();

    node * g = new node();
    g->setData(data1);
    list->setHead(g);
    node * b = new node();
    list->appendNode(b);
    node * k = new node();
    list->appendNode(k);
    list->showInfo();
return 0;
}
```

any hints and direction is appreciated.

EDIT: stepping through shows it breaks within iosfwd. the code it breaks in is:

```
static size_t __CLRCALL_OR_CDECL length(const _Elem *_First)
        {   // find length of null-terminated string
        return (*_First == 0 ? 0
            : _CSTD strlen(_First));
        }
```

Comment: The `nullptr` value will be 0x00000000, not 0x00000005. Is there a possibility of some uninitialized memory somewhere? You don't show how the nodes are allocated, etc.

Comment: _"I'm assuming it's my appendNode function"_ Well, don't make assumptions. Use a debugger and step through instead.

Comment: the break says: Unhandled exception at 0x009F5B31 in Exam3P2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Comment: Its pretty obvious that the call to showInfo shown in your code is not called on a null pointer. Have you stepped through it in the debugger? Looked at the call stack when this occurs?

Comment: You didn't set the data for nodes `b` and  `k`. Could it be that the default value for the `data` field in `node` is a nullptr?

Comment: Sounds likely - for future reference, posting a full but minimal example ("Minimal Criminal") is usually much more productive.

Comment: I'm literally hating myself right now... @Heike